# how can I put the comment show on form

Tags: django

I have to let the "comment" show in the `report_detail.html`

I an using Django 2.2 , I have tried to add some code to `views.py` but failed. The Report need to show the comment below, however, I try add some code in `views.py` and `report_detail.html` but it can not work, how can I do ? thank you

**models.py**

```
class Report(models.Model):
    done = models.TextField('what done')
    willDo = models.TextField('will do')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.done

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('report_detail', args=[str(self.id)])


class Comment(models.Model): 
    report = models.ForeignKey(
        Report, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='comments',
    )

    comment = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )


    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('report_list')
```

**views.py**

```
class ReportDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Report
    template_name = 'report_detail.html'
    login_url = 'login'
```

**report_detail.html**

```
<div class="article-entry">
  <h2>{{ object.done }}</h2>
    <p>by {{ object.author }} | {{ object.date }}</p>
    <p>{{ object.willDo }}</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Where is the comment in the template? An "it's not working" question like this needs to show where it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you want to do is just this:

```
<div class="article-entry">
  <h2>{{ object.done }}</h2>
  <p>by {{ object.author }} | {{ object.date }}</p>
  <p>{{ object.willDo }}</p>
  {% for comment in object.comments.all %}
      <p>{{ comment.comment }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the report has a comment linked?

Comment: I can put comment in my admin but just don't know how to show in report_detail.html, the  <p>{{ object.willDo }}</p> can show no problem but comment,,,,.

Comment: Can you try now?

Comment: error shows "RelatedManager' object is not iterable"

Comment: Okey, that was my mistake. I've added a `.all`in the answer. Try now, it should work!